# KVM guest clock sync with host

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, synchronization, ntpd, time

I'm running KVM w/ centos 6.x.

My guest vm clocks are booting with a 1-2 second lag from their host.  My clocksource for the host is ntp.  My clocksource for the guest is "kvm-clock", but I need to run ntpd on the guest as well.

It takes roughly 3 minutes for ntpd to correct the time after boot. I'll see this in /var/log/messages

```
ntpd[1512]: time reset +1.217409 s
```

But, by this time, our application has already started and it doesn't handle the 1-2 sec time jump very well.

Is this clock difference between the host/guest normal?  Is there a way to force the ntpd to set the time earlier in the boot process?

Answer (score 1):

If your application requires the clock to be synced, add *ntp-wait* to its init script before it is started. Usage is simple, but here is the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntp-wait).

EDIT: If you want to sync time as quickly as possible when booting the VM, before starting ntpd as a daemon, run `sntp` as explained in the documentation for [Deprecating ntpdate](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Dev/DeprecatingNtpdate#Run_once_set_the_time_ASAP).

Comment: that would work, however it takes ~3 minutes for ntpd to synchronize... which is a really long time.

Comment: This comment about sync time might be helpful for you. http://lists.ntp.org/pipermail/questions/2006-November/012096.html